# ¿Cómo rellenar un array con método filter?

Tags: javascript

Tal cómo se puede rellenar un **array** con el método `map`. ¿Por qué no me funciona con `filter`?

```js
(function(){
var a = 1;  
var set = Array.apply(null,{length: 25}).filter(function(){
  return (typeof arguments[1] == "undefined") ? a++ : arguments[1];
});
  console.log(set);
})();
```

Comment: `filter` no rellena arreglos, crea un arreglo nuevo con la condición que le mandes dentro de la función. El problema aquí es que tu arreglo está vacío, por lo que no hay elementos con los que comparar tu condición de `filter` por ende tu arreglo siempre regresa vacío.

Comment: porque map crea un nuevo array con los valores que tú quieras, mientras que filter crea un nuevo array con los **valores originales** que cumplan la condición. Además, deberías mirar `arguments[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que el método `Filter` crea un nuevo `array` con los elementos del `array` principal que cumplan una condición

Te dejo un ejemplo de su correcto funcionamiento:

```js
(function(){
var listado = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var set = listado.filter(function(dato){
  return (dato > 5) ? true : false
});
  console.log(set);
})();
```

En este ejemplo estoy generando un nuevo `array` con todos los valores que sean mayores a 5, cuando el método devuelve `true` significa que ese elemento ha pasado la condición y puede ser agregado al nuevo `array` pero cuando devuelve `false` significa obviamente que no pasó la condición y es ignorado.